# What is the body of __hash__ function for the type int in cython python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, cython, built-in

I am curious as to how `__hash__` is implemented for the `int` type in python3 specifically [cython](https://github.com/cython/cython).

This function `hash` I believe calls `__hash__` on its arguement.

```py
print(hash(1))
>>> 1
print(hash(2))
>>> 2
print(hash(-1))
>>> 2
(2).__hash__
>>> <method-wrapper '__hash__' of int object at 0x1048dd930>
(2).__hash__()
>>> 2
```

Can someone show me the implementation?

Comment: It's in Objects/longobject.c, look for `long_hash()`.  https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Objects/longobject.c

Comment: Also worth reading the comments in: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Python/pyhash.c

Comment: Thank you if you want to post this as an answer please go ahead. The comments in source are enlightening.

Comment: You probably mean CPython? Cython doesn't redefine `int.__hash__`